# How to speed up multi-curve plotting?

Tags: plotting, graphics, performance-tuning

The following example is a very simplified version of the problem I'm working with, though I hope it still captures the essentials.  First, the definitions:

```
sigmoid[s_, a_][x_] := (a (-s + x))/Sqrt[1 + a^2 (s - x)^2];

plots[params_] := Module[{fns},
   fns = sigmoid @@ # & /@ params;
   Plot[#[x] & /@ fns, {x, -20, 20}, ImageSize -> Small]];
```

The `plots` function produces a plot containing as many sigmoid curves as there are parameter sets in the list `params`.  E.g., with 5 parameter sets (differing only in the first parameter):

```
plots[{{-10, 1}, {-5, 1}, {0, 1}, {5, 1}, {10, 1}}]
```

`plots` produces

[image: 5-curve plot]

More typically, however, I need to run `plots` with an argument consisting of ~100 sets of parameters, and I'm finding it to take considerably longer than I had expected.  (Maybe I've gotten spoiled!)

For example, running

```
plots[{#, 1} & /@ Array[# &, 100, {-15, 15}]]
```

takes ~40s on my desktop.  Does this sound right?

Currently I am in the process of producing several figures each consisting of a grid containing ~100 plots of comparable complexity (i.e. ~100 curves/plot), so I need to find ways to significantly speed this up.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

NB: The details of the `sigmoid` function should not be an important aspect of the proposed optimization, since I chose this function for this example only because it is significantly simpler than the function that I am actually working with.  (For one thing, the latter is parametrized by three rather than two numbers.  Nevertheless, it produces s-shaped curves looking very similar those produced by `sigmoid`.)

Comment: You might find a non-trivial speed increase if you switch to `ListLinePlot`. A fair bit of time is spent in `Plot` trying to "inspect" your function and determine how to sample it adaptively. This is helpful when it comes to discontinuities/exclusions, etc. However, if your function is smooth, you can just choose a fixed sampling grid and use that for all values of your parameter. Also, with 100 values of the parameter/plot, you might also want to reconsider if `Plot` is indeed what you want to use... perhaps a 2D plot (`ArrayPlot`) might be more useful.

Comment: Thanks!  Switching to `ListLinePlot` made a huge difference.  Please post your comment so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might find a non-trivial speed increase if you switch to `ListLinePlot`. A fair bit of time is spent in `Plot` trying to "inspect" your function and determine how to sample it adaptively — for each curve being plotted. This is helpful when it comes to discontinuities/exclusions, etc., but starts to get out of hand when you have a lot of curves to plot.

If your function is smooth, you can just choose a fixed sampling grid and use that for all values of your parameter. For example, reformulating your `plots` function as:

```
plotsL[params_, {xmin_, xmax_, dx_}] := Module[{fns, xgrid},
    fns = sigmoid @@ # & /@ params;
    xgrid = Range[xmin, xmax, dx];
    ListLinePlot[#[xgrid] & /@ fns, ImageSize -> Small, DataRange -> {xmin, xmax}]
];

plotsL[{{-10, 1}, {-5, 1}, {0, 1}, {5, 1}, {10, 1}}, {-20, 20, 0.05}]
```

[image]

This should be much faster than using just `Plot` by itself.